# Deleting via Batch file

Tags: batch-file, delete-file

I want to create a batch file to delete the following path across the network via automated scripting.

So far I'm using :

```
REM <start>
@echo off
rmdir /s /q c:\users\%allusersprofile%\ppTemp\
REM <end>
```

Where `%alluserprofiles%` would be each individual user and `ppTemp` is the dir that needs removed.

The code above isn't working.

Help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  "The code above isn't working" is an unhelpful statement.  Could you give us examples of what is IS doing (error messages, unexpected behavior, etc.)

Comment: Please edit your post to include the actual error message that you receive.

Answer (score 1):

The environment variable reference **%AllUsersProfile%** returns a fully qualified path, so prefixing it with `C:\users\` in the **rmdir** command is redundant. It also returns the path for program data storage for *ALL USERS*, not individual users; it's not clear from your question which behavior you want.

As an example, the result I see for `echo %AllUsersProfile%` is

- on Windows 7:    `C:\ProgramData`
- on Windows XP: `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users`

For the **UserProfile** environment variable, `echo %UserProfile%` returns

- on Win7:    `C:\Users\MyUserName`
- on WinXP: `C:\Documents and Settings\MyUserName`

So assuming you're using Windows 7 or Vista, you probably want to change the **rmdir** command to:

```
rmdir /s /q "%UserProfile%\ppTemp\"
```

which should resolve to a path of `C:\Users\username\ppTemp\`.

Comment: double-quote the path or will not work and will delete other folders if username folder have spaces. "%UserProfile%\ppTemp\"